# How to assign values to a vector in pairs of 10 in R?

Tags: r

I want to assign in pairs of 10 elements of a vector to a certain value. How can I do that without manually writing out an assignment for each 10th element?

```
X_mean <- 4.5;
X <- matrix(1, nrow=40, ncol=2);
X[1:10,2] <- 0 - X_mean;
X[11:20,2] <- 3 - X_mean;
X[21:30,2] <- 5 - X_mean;
X[31:40,2] <- 10 - X_mean;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create your matrix `X` and vector `X_mean`, you could do:

```
X[,2] <- rep(c(0,3,5, 10) - X_mean, each = 10)
```